# spurious "containment" in std::set of pointers

Tags: c++, stl, stdset

A set of pointers is reporting that it "contains" a brand-new object, even though this object was just created, and has a memory address which differs from those already in the set.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class foo {
  public:
    int x;
    foo(int x) : x(x) {}
};

int main() {
    vector<foo> my_vector;
    set<foo*, bool (*)(foo*, foo*)> my_set([](foo* left, foo* right) { return left->x < right->x; });

    my_vector.reserve(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        my_vector.emplace_back(i);
        my_set.emplace(&my_vector[i]);
    }
    foo temp(4);
    if (my_set.count(&temp))
        cout << "But why?" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This behavior *DOES NOT* occur if `temp` is initialized using an integer outside the range [0, 10). It's as if the integer `x` is being used to determine *equality*, as opposed to just priority / precedence.

The behavior I want is that distinct objects (i.e., with distinct memory locations) *always* be treated as distinct objects in the set, and that the objects' values `x` be used to order the elements. How do I achieve this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Your comparator doesn't compare pointers, but values they point to. Two distinct pointers may very well point to equivalent data. You want a comparator that compares the data, and then pointers themselves (in order to break ties).

Comment: Please help me understand. I thought that the comparator was ONLY used to determine precedence / priority / ordering, and not to determine membership / equality. If this is incorrect, how exactly is the comparator used?

Comment: In your lambda, If both values x are equal, you want to compare the pointers

Comment: `std::set` cannot contain equivalent elements, where "equivalent" is defined as "neither is smaller than the other" (using the provided comparator for "smaller"). The comparator is **primarily** used for efficient searching - the fact that elements end up in sorted order is essentially a side effect of implementation.

Comment: You might want to read the docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Comment: @IgorTandetnik interesting. Is there a way to use pointer-equality for _equality_, and the comparator for comparison?

Comment: The whole reason `std::set` can implement things like `count` and `find` efficiently is because it uses the comparator for looking up elements. Internally, it's a balanced binary search tree. You could use `std::find`, as in `if (std::find(my_set.begin(), my_set.end(), &temp) != my_set.end()) ...` - this performs a linear scan using "normal" equality. But then you kinda defeat the point of using `std::set` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for the comments. Here is a solution that achieves the desired behavior:

```cpp
int main() {
    set<foo*, bool (*)(foo*, foo*)> my_set([](foo* left, foo* right) {
        if (left->x == right->x)
            return std::less<foo*>{}(left, right);
        return left->x < right->x;
    });
    // ....
    return 0;
}
```

**EDITED** to reflect @Igor Tandetnik's helpful comment!

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson. `left < right` exhibits undefined behavior unless the two pointers point into the same array. To compare two arbitrary pointers, use `std::less<foo*>{}(left, right)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So you mean the custom comparator should be removed because the default comparator of [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is `std::less`?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you need to use `std::less` as shown, rather than the built-in operator `<`, when comparing two pointers that may not point into the same array. The built-in operator is only defined on pointers into the same array, whereas `std::less` defines a total order.

Answer (score 1):

In a `std::set`, for two values L and R, if neither `L<R` nor `R<L`, they are considered equal.  There is no separate of "priority/ordering" and equality, as you thought there might be.

> How do I achieve this behavior?

Use a container other than `std::set`.  For example a vector which you keep sorted.

Comment: But my lambda only defines what it means for L < R. How would the set even interpret the meaning of R < L, when I have provided no such lambda?

Comment: @BD107: L and R are just placeholder names.  Call them Bob and Sally.  If you define the lambda comparator for Bob and Sally, the `std::set` implementation can invoke it for `(Bob, Sally)` or `(Sally, Bob)` without asking you for permission.  It just passes the arguments in the other order.

Comment: Hmm. So the comparator is used to determine precedence _and_ equality / membership. Do you think I could achieve the desired behavior using a `multiset`? Suppose that I can guarantee each object `emplace`d will have a unique address.

Comment: If I used a `vector`, then I'd have to implement binary search and insertion myself in order to keep it sorted. What if I used a `multiset`?

Comment: You can try using a `multiset` but I am quite sure you will find it does not do what you want, because again it considers equality to be a concept built on top of ordering (if X is not before Y and Y is not before X, then X and Y are equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

You could first check for equality in your lambda. If this check fails you can calculate the order relationship...